# C - Socket Networking - string's won't produce equality

Tags: c, sockets, memset

I have been doing socket networking in C, for an application that will take a password from the client side for verification at the server. I've set everything up and the sockets communicate but when I send a string over and use strcmp() the strings, despite being the same when printed out, won't return 0 (which I believe indicates the strings are the same) like so:

Note the client and server side are separate programs, going through localhost on my machine.

```
/*Client Side */

char password[64] = {0};

fgets(password, 64, stdin);

write(sockfd, password, 64);



/*Server Side */

char password[64] = "password";

char password_buffer[64];

read(newsockfd, password_buffer, 64);

if(strcmp(password, password_buffer) != 0)
    {
    printf("Password Incorrect\n");
    {
else 
    {
    printf("Password correct\n");
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It has occured to me that the use of bzero or memset may be involved, although I'm not sure how these are implicated.

Comment: You ignore the return value of `read`, so you have no idea how many bytes you read. How are you expecting `strcmp` to know how that?

Comment: `read` may read less than 64 bytes. It the returns the number of bytes read. If it's not 64 you need to repeat with the rest

Comment: probably a string termination issue. Examine `password_buffer`'s memory after the `read`. And I would initialize it to all 0s too, and only read 63 bytes to ensure the last one is `\0`.

Comment: So I would have to fill the rest of the memory with zero's? Apologies if that's a silly question, I am pretty new to C. Thanks by the way guys!

Comment: @yano Given the posted code, that shouldn't matter.  The sending code sends 64 bytes, all NUL except for the initial "password" string - *IF* the sending code actually sent 64 bytes as the return value from `write()` isn't checked, either.

Comment: @milesb Filling the rest of the memory with zeroes probably won't help. But it's impossible to be sure because we have no idea what protocol you are using on top of TCP. Does the other side always send exactly 64 bytes? If so, what happens if the password is less than 64 bytes? If not, how does the receiver know when it has the whole password?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have thought about that, I was hoping that having a fixed sized array on each size would be okay, it hasn't been a problem so far, although I could quite easily be proved wrong! I was given the networking code from an old textbook with a fairly limited explanation, although it does use AF_INET which I believe is IP, if that makes things a little easier to understand? If it does turn out to be a problem, have you any suggestions as to how to fix it? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @AndrewHenle Ahh, you're right. Just looked at the server code apparently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fgets(password, 64, stdin);` likely adds a trailing new-line character (`\n`) at end of string. Remove it from the client string after `fgets`, or add one at end of compare string on the server side.
To remove the trailing new-line from the client string, use e.g. this:
`password[strcspn(password, "\r\n")] = 0;`